# Can't find couple of views in android studio palette

Tags: android

I have a weird issue in android studio 
I try to find some controls view in android studio palette but i can't find that . but it's exist in xml view !! 
for example expended list or image switcher and etc . Do you know why ?? 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdPGP.png)

Comment: Please be more specific. Add some screenshots...

Comment: @Jakob I added image right now